# How can I get only responses tweets?

Tags: python, twitter

I need to retrieve specific data from twitter.

I'd like to get all the responses tweets received by a specific user (which is not the authenticating user of the program). Is there a way to achieve this? Right now I'm thinking about using the search function and see if the 'in_reply_to_user_id_str' matches the id of the user I want.

But this means that I need to filter a lot of data to find the one I want

Edit: I'm using the [Python-Twitter-Tools](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter)

Answer (score 0):

If it is the authenticating user, you can directly get the response tweets using the 'mentions timeline'. As the user is not the authenticating user, you have two options here.

1. [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/public)
   Use the filter endpoint along with the 'follow' parameter. Pass the required 'user_id' to the follow paramenter and it will return the followings. You will have to check the 'in_reply_to_user_id_str' in order to isolate the replies(responses).

   > Tweets created by the user.
   >   Tweets which are retweeted by the user.
   >   **Replies to any Tweet created by the user.**
   >   Retweets of any Tweet created by the user.
   >   Manual replies, created without pressing a reply button.

   Python-Twitter-Tools supports Streaming API. Streaming API is realtime and better than Search API considering the completeness.
2. [Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)
   Every response tweet contains the "@username" tag. You can searching using "@username" tag and then filter the tweets using 'in_reply_to_user_id_str' as you have mentioned.

Considering the two options, Streaming API will help you to get what you need easily and reliably.